# How do I add a single marker to a Google Map v3?

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

In the code below, I've been displaying the greyscale of the map using Google Maps v3 with the desired latitude and longitude from the DB. Can someone help me figure out how I can put only one marker at the desired latitude and longitude.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var latitude = <?php echo $store_details->latitude; ?>; 
var longitude = <?php echo $store_details->longitude; ?>;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'Greyscale';

function initialize() {
    var graystyle = [{
        featureType: "all",
        elementType: "all",
        stylers: [ { saturation: -100 }, { visibility: "on" } ]
    }];

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: brooklyn,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, MY_MAPTYPE_ID]
        },
        mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);

    var styledMapOptions = {
        name: "Greyscale"
    };

    var grayMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(graystyle, styledMapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, grayMapType);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the docs?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Comment: Tried ! but over confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });
```

this is the syntax 
 and if you want example [click here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#markers_v3)

Answer (score 0):

I use a function to be able to place as many markers as I want without coding the same lines time after time (markers is a global array):

```
var markers = createMarker(map, new google.maps.LatLng(50.746853, 5.497167), MyTitle, MyMarkerImage, '#FF0099');

function createMarker(map, pos, titleString, myJPGfile, colorCode) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
                        map: map, 
                        position: pos, 
                        title: titleString, 
                        icon: myJPGfile,
                        color: colorCode });

    return marker;
}
```